# Error with Elasticsearch Helpers Scan API when using query parameter

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch Helpers Scan API to output all bulk records from my index.
I wanted to use the query parameter to filter the certain records first and then use scan for which I referred to the standard doc for scan here . But as soon as I apply the query parameter it gives me a 400 error. Here is my line of code and error.

Script:

```
import elasticsearch
import elasticsearch.exceptions 
import elasticsearch.helpers as helpers
import time


es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch('XXX.XX.XX.XX'],retry_on_timeout=True)  


scanResp = helpers.scan(client=es,scroll="5m",query={"match":{"channel_id": "34"}},index="my-index",timeout="10m",size=500)

resp={}
start_time = time.time()
for resp in scanResp:
    data = resp
    #print data.values()[3]


print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Output:

> RequestError: TransportError(400,
>   u'SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [init_scan],
>   all shards failed; shardFailures
>   {[lEAncRHvQHKpPqlfw1NWEQ][dev-godam][0]:
>   SearchParseException[[dev-godam][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure
>   [Failed to parse source [{"match": {"master_channel_id": "34"}}]]];
>   nested: SearchParseException[[dev-godam][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse
>   Failure [No parser for element [match]]];
>   }{[lEAncRHvQHKpPqlfw1NWEQ][dev-godam][1]:
>   SearchParseException[[dev-godam][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure
>   [Failed to parse source [{"match": {"master_channel_id": "34"}}]]];
>   nested: SearchParseException[[dev-godam][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse
>   Failure [No parser for element [match]]];
>   }{[lEAncRHvQHKpPqlfw1NWEQ][dev-godam][2]:
>   SearchParseException[[dev-godam][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure
>   [Failed to parse source [{"match": {"master_channel_id": "34"}}]]];
>   nested: SearchParseException[[dev-godam][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse
>   Failure [No parser for element [match]]];
>   }{[lEAncRHvQHKpPqlfw1NWEQ][dev-godam][3]:
>   SearchParseException[[dev-godam][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure
>   [Failed to parse source [{"match": {"master_channel_id": "34"}}]]];
>   nested: SearchParseException[[dev-godam][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse
>   Failure [No parser for element [match]]];
>   }{[lEAncRHvQHKpPqlfw1NWEQ][dev-godam][4]:
>   SearchParseException[[dev-godam][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure
>   [Failed to parse source [{"match": {"master_channel_id": "34"}}]]];
>   nested: SearchParseException[[dev-godam][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse
>   Failure [No parser for element [match]]]; }]')

Looked on the internet but not sure what I have done wrong here.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `body` parameter should be a dictionary instead of a string and use double quotes instead of single quotes, try this:

```
scanResp = helpers.scan(client=es,scroll="5m",query={"query":{"match": {"channel_id": "34"}}},index='stg-index',timeout="10m",size=500)
```

Comment: tried using what u mentioned , still getting error, here is what i modified                 scanResp = helpers.scan(client=es,scroll="5m",query={"match_all": {}},index='stg-index',timeout="10m",size=500)

Comment: Well, code 39 is the ASCII code for the single quote, so you must have a single quote left somewhere.

Comment: Wierd but i double checked. Havent missed any single quote.

Comment: Can you update your question with the error you're now getting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93169/discussion-between-amit-p-and-val).